# Downloading a Grails plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Is there a Maven repo from where I can download grails plugin files.

I know I can do

> `install-plugin name`

but I want to store it in my repo.

Comment: You shouldn't do `grails install-plugin name`, you should put the plugin resolution into the plugins section of `BuildConfig.groovy`, ie: `compile ":mail:1.0.1"`

Comment: Can you please explain what the difference is?

Comment: @micha [install-plugin is deprecated as of Grails 2](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Command%20Line/install-plugin.html), it didn't allow you to manage dependencies, and so the way to do it now is via `BuildConfig` :)

Comment: I used Buildconfig to add local plugins and install-plugin to install plugins like jms and activemq and that was in the grials documents. But now I know the right way. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grails Plugin Repo can be found here http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/

or you can browse [Artifactory](http://repo.grails.org/grails/webapp/home.html?12) and search for the plugin you need.