# Error Failed to resolve dependencies grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I get `Error Failed to resolve dependencies` error when I try to run, clean, or compile. My `BuildConfig.groovy` file is as follows:

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

//Start company specific
//set plugin directory (needed for having plugins in perforce)
grails.project.plugins.dir="./plugins"

//set the grails work dir (contains proxy configuration file)
grails.work.dir="./work"
//End company specific

// uncomment (and adjust settings) to fork the JVM to isolate classpaths
//grails.project.fork = [
//   run: [maxMemory:1024, minMemory:64, debug:false, maxPerm:256]
//]

grails.war.copyToWebInf = { args ->
    fileset(dir:"dbmsScripts") {
        include(name: "js/**")
        include(name: "css/**")
        include(name: "images/**")
        include(name: "dbmsScripts/**")
        include(name: "WEB-INF/**")
    }
}


grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "verbose" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"

        mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/" // needed for searchable plugin
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'

    }

    plugins {
        //Run time
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":resources:1.2.2"
        runtime ":jquery:1.10.2"
        runtime ":jquery-ui:1.10.3"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.3.2"
        runtime ":searchable:0.6.8"
        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

        //Build
        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

        //Compile time
        compile ':cache:1.0.1'
        compile ':quartz:1.0.1'
        compile ':mail:1.0.7'
        compile ":class-domain-uml:0.1.5"

    }

}
```

I have installed the `quartz` and `mail` plugins in the past and they are available in `plugins` directory.

[image: plugins directory view]

When I checkout new from source control, and try to run I get the problem. The debug messages as follows:

```
.
.
.
==== mavenCentral: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/searchable/0.6.8/searchable-0.6.8.pom
  -- artifact org.grails.plugins#searchable;0.6.8!searchable.zip:

  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/searchable/0.6.8/searchable-0.6.8.zip

==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/: tried

  http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/searchable/0.6.8/searchable-0.6.8.pom

  -- artifact org.grails.plugins#searchable;0.6.8!searchable.zip:



http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/searchable/0.6.8/searchable-0.6.8.zip

        module not found: org.grails.plugins#quartz;1.0.1

    ==== grailsPlugins: tried

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#quartz;1.0.1!quartz.zip:

      C:\Development\ODBC_SGullipalli\OrgaDbControl/lib/quartz-1.0.1.zip

      C:\Development\ODBC_SGullipalli\OrgaDbControl\.\plugins\cache-1.0.1/lib/quartz-1.0.1.zip

      C:\Development\ODBC_SGullipalli\OrgaDbControl\.\plugins\class-domain-uml-0.1.5/lib/quartz-1.0.1.zip

      C:\Development\ODBC_SGullipalli\OrgaDbControl\.\plugins\database-migration-1.3.2/lib/quartz-1.0.1.zip

      C:\Development\ODBC_SGullipalli\OrgaDbControl\.\plugins\gsp-resources-0.4.4/lib/quartz-1.0.1.zip

      C:\Development\ODBC_SGullipalli\OrgaDbControl\.\plugins\hibernate-2.2.4/lib/quartz-1.0.1.zip

      C:\Development\ODBC_SGullipalli\OrgaDbControl\.\plugins\jquery-1.10.2/lib/quartz-1.0.1.zip

      C:\Development\ODBC_SGullipalli\OrgaDbControl\.\plugins\jquery-1.8.3/lib/quartz-1.0.1.zip

      C:\Development\ODBC_SGullipalli\OrgaDbControl\.\plugins\jquery-ui-1.10.3/lib/quartz-1.0.1.zip

      C:\Development\ODBC_SGullipalli\OrgaDbControl\.\plugins\mail-1.0.7/lib/quartz-1.0.1.zip

      C:\Development\ODBC_SGullipalli\OrgaDbControl\.\plugins\quartz-1.0.1/lib/quartz-1.0.1.zip

      C:\Development\ODBC_SGullipalli\OrgaDbControl\.\plugins\resources-1.2/lib/quartz-1.0.1.zip

      C:\Development\ODBC_SGullipalli\OrgaDbControl\.\plugins\resources-1.2.2/lib/quartz-1.0.1.zip

      C:\Development\ODBC_SGullipalli\OrgaDbControl\.\plugins\searchable-0.6.8/lib/quartz-1.0.1.zip

      C:\Development\ODBC_SGullipalli\OrgaDbControl\.\plugins\tomcat-2.2.4/lib/quartz-1.0.1.zip

      C:\Development\ODBC_SGullipalli\OrgaDbControl\.\plugins\webxml-1.4.1/lib/quartz-1.0.1.zip

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\springsource\grails-2.2.4/lib/org.grails.plugins/quartz/ivy-1.0.1.xml
.
.
.

==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\springsource\grails-2.2.4\src\libs/gsp-resources-0.4.4.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#gsp-resources;0.4.4!gsp-resources.jar:

      C:\springsource\grails-2.2.4\src\libs/gsp-resources-0.4.4.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\springsource\grails-2.2.4\dist/gsp-resources-0.4.4.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#gsp-resources;0.4.4!gsp-resources.jar:

      C:\springsource\grails-2.2.4\dist/gsp-resources-0.4.4.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\Development\ODBC_SGullipalli\OrgaDbControl\.\work\cached-installed-plugins/gsp-resources-0.4.4.xml

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#gsp-resources;0.4.4!gsp-resources.jar:

      C:\Development\ODBC_SGullipalli\OrgaDbControl\.\work\cached-installed-plugins/gsp-resources-0.4.4.jar

    ==== grailsHome: tried

      C:\springsource\grails-2.2.4/plugins/gsp-resources-0.4.4.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#gsp-resources;0.4.4!gsp-resources.jar:

      C:\springsource\grails-2.2.4/plugins/gsp-resources-0.4.4.jar

    ==== grailsCentral: tried

      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-gsp-resources/tags/RELEASE_0.4.4/gsp-resources-0.4.4.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#gsp-resources;0.4.4!gsp-resources.jar:

      http://grails.org/plugins/grails-gsp-resources/tags/RELEASE_0.4.4/grails-gsp-resources-0.4.4.jar

    ==== localMavenResolver: tried

      C:\Users\sgullipalli.OS/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/gsp-resources/0.4.4/gsp-resources-0.4.4.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#gsp-resources;0.4.4!gsp-resources.jar:

      C:\Users\sgullipalli.OS/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/gsp-resources/0.4.4/gsp-resources-0.4.4.jar

    ==== mavenCentral: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/gsp-resources/0.4.4/gsp-resources-0.4.4.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#gsp-resources;0.4.4!gsp-resources.jar:

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/gsp-resources/0.4.4/gsp-resources-0.4.4.jar

    ==== http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/: tried

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/gsp-resources/0.4.4/gsp-resources-0.4.4.pom

      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#gsp-resources;0.4.4!gsp-resources.jar:

      http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/gsp-resources/0.4.4/gsp-resources-0.4.4.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.grails.plugins#resources;1.2.2: not found

        :: org.grails.plugins#jquery;1.10.2: not found

        :: org.grails.plugins#jquery-ui;1.10.3: not found

        :: org.grails.plugins#searchable;0.6.8: not found

        :: org.grails.plugins#quartz;1.0.1: not found

        :: org.grails.plugins#mail;1.0.7: not found

        :: org.grails.plugins#class-domain-uml;0.1.5: not found

        :: org.grails.plugins#gsp-resources;0.4.4: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
Resolving [compile] dependencies...
:: resolving dependencies :: org.grails.internal#OrgaDbControl;0.3.8
    confs: [compile]
.
.  
.
found org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.2 in cache
== resolving dependencies org.grails.internal#OrgaDbControl;0.3.8->org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.2 [compile->runtime]
== resolving dependencies org.grails.internal#OrgaDbControl;0.3.8->org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.2 [compile->compile]
== resolving dependencies org.grails.internal#OrgaDbControl;0.3.8->org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.2 [compile->master]
== resolving dependencies org.grails.internal#OrgaDbControl;0.3.8->org.grails#grails-datastore-gorm;1.1.8.RELEASE [compile->default]
cache: Checking cache for: dependency: org.grails#grails-datastore-gorm;1.1.8.RELEASE {compile=[default]}
cache: module revision found in cache: org.grails#grails-datastore-gorm;1.1.8.RELEASE
    found org.grails#grails-datastore-gorm;1.1.8.RELEASE in cache
== resolving dependencies org.grails.internal#OrgaDbControl;0.3.8->org.grails#grails-datastore-gorm;1.1.8.RELEASE [compile->runtime]
== resolving dependencies org.grails.internal#OrgaDbControl;0.3.8->org.grails#grails-datastore-gorm;1.1.8.RELEASE [compile->compile]
== resolving dependencies org.grails.internal#OrgaDbControl;0.3.8->org.grails#grails-datastore-gorm;1.1.8.RELEASE [compile->master]
== resolving dependencies org.grails.internal#OrgaDbControl;0.3.8->org.grails#grails-datastore-core;1.1.8.RELEASE [compile->default]
cache: Checking cache for: dependency: org.grails#grails-datastore-core;1.1.8.RELEASE {compile=[default]}
cache: module revision found in cache: org.grails#grails-datastore-core;1.1.8.RELEASE
    found org.grails#grails-datastore-core;1.1.8.RELEASE in cache
== resolving dependencies org.grails.internal#OrgaDbControl;0.3.8->org.grails#grails-datastore-core;1.1.8.RELEASE [compile->runtime]
== resolving dependencies org.grails.internal#OrgaDbControl;0.3.8->org.grails#grails-datastore-core;1.1.8.RELEASE [compile->compile]
== resolving dependencies org.grails.internal#OrgaDbControl;0.3.8->org.grails#grails-datastore-core;1.1.8.RELEASE [compile->master]
== resolving dependencies org.grails.internal#OrgaDbControl;0.3.8->org.grails#grails-datastore-simple;1.1.8.RELEASE [compile->default]
cache: Checking cache for: dependency: org.grails#grails-datastore-simple;1.1.8.RELEASE {compile=[default]}
cache: module revision found in cache: org.grails#grails-datastore-simple;1.1.8.RELEASE
    found org.grails#grails-datastore-simple;1.1.8.RELEASE in cache
== resolving dependencies org.grails.internal#OrgaDbControl;0.3.8->org.grails#grails-datastore-simple;1.1.8.RELEASE [compile->runtime]
== resolving dependencies org.grails.internal#OrgaDbControl;0.3.8->org.grails#grails-datastore-simple;1.1.8.RELEASE [compile->compile]
== resolving dependencies org.grails.internal#OrgaDbControl;0.3.8->org.grails#grails-datastore-simple;1.1.8.RELEASE [compile->master]
    resolved ivy file produced in C:\Users\sgullipalli.OS\.grails\ivy-cache\resolved-org.grails.internal-OrgaDbControl-0.3.8.xml
:: downloading artifacts ::
    [NOT REQUIRED] org.codehaus.groovy#groovy-all;2.0.8!groovy-all.jar
    [NOT REQUIRED] commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.3!commons-beanutils.jar
    [NOT REQUIRED] commons-el#commons-el;1.0!commons-el.jar
.
.
.
[NOT REQUIRED] org.springframework#spring-jms;3.1.4.RELEASE!spring-jms.jar
    [NOT REQUIRED] org.springframework#spring-orm;3.1.4.RELEASE!spring-orm.jar
    [NOT REQUIRED] org.springframework#spring-tx;3.1.4.RELEASE!spring-tx.jar
    [NOT REQUIRED] org.springframework#spring-web;3.1.4.RELEASE!spring-web.jar
    [NOT REQUIRED] org.springframework#spring-webmvc;3.1.4.RELEASE!spring-webmvc.jar
    [NOT REQUIRED] org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.2!slf4j-api.jar
    [NOT REQUIRED] org.grails#grails-datastore-gorm;1.1.8.RELEASE!grails-datastore-gorm.jar
    [NOT REQUIRED] org.grails#grails-datastore-core;1.1.8.RELEASE!grails-datastore-core.jar
    [NOT REQUIRED] org.grails#grails-datastore-simple;1.1.8.RELEASE!grails-datastore-simple.jar
:: resolution report :: resolve 218ms :: artifacts dl 48ms
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      compile     |   54  |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   54  |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    report for org.grails.internal#OrgaDbControl;0.3.8 compile produced in C:\Users\sgullipalli.OS\.grails\ivy-cache\org.grails.internal-OrgaDbControl-compile.xml
    resolve done (218ms resolve - 48ms download)
| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.grails.plugins:resources:1.2.2
- org.grails.plugins:jquery:1.10.2
- org.grails.plugins:jquery-ui:1.10.3
- org.grails.plugins:searchable:0.6.8
- org.grails.plugins:quartz:1.0.1
- org.grails.plugins:mail:1.0.7
- org.grails.plugins:class-domain-uml:0.1.5
- org.grails.plugins:gsp-resources:0.4.4
```

How could it be resolved?

Comment: Have you upgraded the project??

Comment: Do you mean the new modifications to the project or the grails version?

Comment: No. I didn't upgrade the version. I forgot to mention that I am using grails version 2.2.4

Comment: refresh dependencies

Comment: tried refreshing dependencies. Got the same error when I ran `refresh-dependencies`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Sometimes it seems like people are playing Hide and Seek with these plugins.
I also have an older (grails 2.2.5) project that didn't work when I checked it out of source control.  This hit me because I'm on a new computer that didn't have a local maven or ivy cache.

I added the following two repos in the repositories section of BuildConfig.groovy

```
mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"
```

and was able to get my project to refresh.

I found the first link here https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSEARCHABLE-224 while trying to get the searchable plugin to work.

I found the second link in  [Downloading a Grails plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136375/downloading-a-grails-plugin)