# move Grails project from older to newest version of Intellij Idea IDE

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I've developed my Grails project  in a machine that has Idea 13 installed.
Now I've moved in another machine and I've installed the latest version of the IDE.

I've installed Grails (ver. 2.2.1) and Groovy (ver. 2.4.6) giving the path variables as described in their installation instructions. I've created a new project from existing source but when I try to run it, it gives me errors about plugins.

Plugins are missing and I cannot install in the project because the tab in the menu Tools -> Grails -> Plugins (or right click on the root of the project -> Grails -> Plugins) does not exists. I've tried with creating a brand new Grails project and the tab exists, so maybe it depends on the way I've imported the project.

Here it is the BuildConfig.groovy content:

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}.war"

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {

    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.20'

    }

    plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.8.0"
        runtime ":resources:1.1.6"

        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.4"

        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

        runtime ":database-migration:1.1"

        compile ':cache:1.0.0'

        compile ":ckeditor:4.4.1.0"


    }
}
```

Here it is the error in Grails console:

```
Error |
Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.grails.plugins:cache:1.0.0
- org.grails.plugins:ckeditor:4.4.1.0
```

How can I import it without receiving errors in building code?

EDIT: 
I've created a brand new project. It installs default plugins but does not allow to add new plugins via Tools->Grails->Plugins

The error is (i.e. log4j plugin installation):

```
|Resolving plugin log4j-xml. Please wait...
|Error resolving plugin [name:log4j-xml, group:org.grails.plugins, version:0.2]. Plugin not found.
Error |
Plugin not found for name [log4j-xml] and version [0.2]
```

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting? Thanks

Comment: @Biswas error log added

Comment: You should upgrade your cache and ckeditor plugin. They are outdated and it cannot be found in maven repo so you are getting the error. Upgrade it to cache:1.1.8 and ckeditor:4.5.4.0 and it will work fine. For reference https://grails.org/plugin/cache and https://grails.org/plugin/ckeditor Thanks

Comment: @Biswas I've changed the versions, but I have same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem on my own.

The solution is the same found here: [Error Failed to resolve dependencies grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28692748/error-failed-to-resolve-dependencies-grails/29190512#29190512)